# Dynamic Forms using Select dropdown (multiple) - Pre-Populate based on decisions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm wondering if someone can help or point me in the right direction for some material on this. I've looked but cannot find a good example.

Basically, I have a form with 5 drop down selects. Upon submission the selects must all add to <=100 (not more). So what I would like is to have the first dropdown have values form 0-100 , and depending on what is chosen, the remainder of the selects only have values that would not allow over a 100% submission.

```
eg:
Select1 - 40% chosen
Select2 - 0-60% is what is left to be chosen, created dynamically
Select3 - same as 2 above
Select4 - same as 2 above
Select5 - same as 2 above
```

in an ideal world, cause no-one ever does things in order .. when someone chooses their first select value (any of the 5 dropdown presented to them) , all others will update dynamically to be 0-x ... x would be 100-value chosen in first drop down. and so on each time something is chosen.

See, it is so confusing I'm sure I just confused everyone :)

Any initial thoughts or questions ?

Comment: You didn't tag Javacript, does it mean you want it to be with a form that sends the request to the server to calculate it ?

Comment: looking for any and all options. I updated the tags. Good point.